# Google Charts: is there a way to hide certain series from the tooltip?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

On https://www.mscha.org/knmi/summer_graph_wst.cgi?station=260&year=2022&month=0, I have several data series that I'm showing in the chart, but don't want to show in the tooltip (with `focusTarget: 'category'`).

[image: screenshot]

(The entries in the tooltip from `(Warme dag)` until `(Grens tropische dag)` are useless.)

You can easily exclude a data series from the legend, using `visibleInLegend: false`, but there doesn't seem to be a corresponding `visibleInTooltip: false`.
Setting the `label` of the series to `''` or `null` doesn't help either, it wil just show the data without a label.

If the value is `null`, then that series won't be listed in the tooltip. but that is not the case here, we have a value which is dramn in the chart.  I tried (e.g.) `{ v: 20, f: null }`, `{ v: 20, f: '' }` and `{ v: 20, f: ' '}` without the desired result.

Is there a way to do this, without writing the complete tooltip HTML myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it turns out that you *can* skip certain series in a tooltip (with `focusTarget: 'category'`), simply by setting `tooltip: false` for the specific series.

This doesn't seem to be [documented](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#:%7E:text=Default%3A%20%27single%27-,series,-An%20array%20of), but I found it in another script I wrote a few years ago.  No idea how I found it out at that time.

For instance, on the [mentioned page](https://www.mscha.org/knmi/summer_graph_wst.cgi?station=260&year=2022&month=0) I am now using:

```
series: {
        0: { color: '#cccccc', labelInLegend: 'max.temp.', type: 'line' },
        1: { color: '#ffdd55', labelInLegend: 'warm', type: 'line', pointSize: 4 },
        2: { color: '#ffaa55', labelInLegend: 'zomers', type: 'line', pointSize: 5 },
        3: { color: '#ff4444', labelInLegend: 'tropisch', type: 'line', pointSize: 6 },
        4: { color: '#e8e8e8', labelInLegend: 'dagen', areaOpacity: 0.25, targetAxisIndex: 1 },
        5: { color: '#f8d680', labelInLegend: 'warm', areaOpacity: 0.25, targetAxisIndex: 1 },
        6: { color: '#ffbb88', labelInLegend: 'zomers', areaOpacity: 0.25, targetAxisIndex: 1 },
        7: { color: '#ff8888', labelInLegend: 'tropisch', areaOpacity: 0.25, targetAxisIndex: 1 },
        8: { color: '#ffdd55', visibleInLegend: false, tooltip: false, type: 'line', lineDashStyle: [4, 6] },
        9: { color: '#ffaa55', visibleInLegend: false, tooltip: false, type: 'line', lineDashStyle: [4, 6] },
        10: { color: '#ff4444', visibleInLegend: false, tooltip: false, type: 'line', lineDashStyle: [4, 6] },
    },
```

and that does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

there are no standard config options that will hide a specific series from the tooltip.
but you can still accomplish without custom tooltips.
first, you will need to use html tooltips, by setting the following config option...

```
  tooltip: {
    isHtml: true
  }
```

when html tooltips are used, we can style the tooltips using CSS

with `focusTarget: 'category'`, each tooltip row will be represented by class:
`.google-visualization-tooltip-item`, this includes the row for the x-axis

use the following CSS to hide a certain series from the tooltip.
the following will hide the second series `'y1'`

```
#chart .google-visualization-tooltip-item:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
}).then(function() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'y0', 'y1', 'y2'],
    [new Date(2020, 10, 13), 100, 50, 25],
    [new Date(2020, 10, 14), 110, 45, 5],
    [new Date(2020, 10, 15), 90, 40, 60],
    [new Date(2020, 10, 16), 80, 30, 10],
    [new Date(2020, 10, 17), 70, 20, 0],
    [new Date(2020, 10, 18), 60, 10, 0],
    [new Date(2020, 10, 19), 50, 5, 0]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ComboChart',
    containerId: 'chart',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      focusTarget: 'category',
      chartArea: {
        left: 60,
        top: 12,
        right: 60,
        bottom: 72,
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%'
      },
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      vAxes: {
        0: {
          titlePosition: 'none',
          textStyle: {
            color: '#febd02',
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 13,
          },
          format: '#',
          gridlines: {
            color: '#eaeaea',
            count: '5',
          },
          interpolateNulls: true,
        },
        1: {
          titlePosition: 'none',
          format: '#',
          gridlines: {
            color: 'transparent'
          },
          interpolateNulls: true,
        },
        2: {
          groupWidth: '100%',
          titlePosition: 'none',
          textStyle: {
            color: '#0284ff',
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 13,
          },
          format: 'decimal',
          gridlines: {
            color: 'transparent'
          },
        },
      },
      hAxis: {
        textStyle: {
          color: '#393939',
          bold: true,
          fontSize: 13,
        },
        format: 'dd MMM. yyyy',
        gridlines: {
          color: 'transparent'
        },
        ticks: data.getDistinctValues(0),
        viewWindow: data.getColumnRange(0)
      },
      series: {
        0: {
          targetAxisIndex: 0,
          type: 'area',
        },
        1: {
          type: 'line'
        },
        2: {
          targetAxisIndex: 2,
          type: 'bars',
          dataOpacity: 0.5,
        },
      },
      colors: [
        '#febd02',
        '#a5a5a5',
        '#0284ff',
      ],
      bar: {
        groupWidth: '35'
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'none'
      },
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true,
        trigger: 'both'
      }
    },
  });
  chart.draw();
});
```

```css
#chart .google-visualization-tooltip-item:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: tip: add option `trigger: 'both'` to the tooltip config option (see above), when you click on the series, this will lock the tooltip in place, and allow you to use dev tools to explore the html that is generated.

Comment: Thanks, @WhiteHat, excellent!  This does the trick.  I like the (standard) look of the HTML tooltips a bit less than the default tooltips, but with a bit more CSS I tweaked the spacing a bit and now it looks good.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that you _can_ leave a specific series out of the tooltip, although that doesn't seem to be documented.  See my answer.